# Sound problem |Internal Speakers recognized as headphones

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a laptop running Lubuntu 15.04. The problem is that my internal speakers are treated as headphones, and the volume of them is controlled by headphones bar at alsa. So if I plug headphones and unplug them, after there is no sound at speakers since the headphones volume value decreases to 0. So the problem is that the speakers are being recognized as headphones instead of speakers. Is there a way to fix this problem?